# how to increment a number only when a certain word from a array gets written in a textbox

Tags: php

my site is written in php and heres the code I have got

```
//good words
        $body = implode(" ", $body_array);
        $niceWords = array("nice", "amazing", "fantastic", "great");
        $body = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|',$niceWords).')\b/','You have used the speical ',$body);

        //Start the Points
        $_SESSION['points'];
        $_SESSION['points']++;
        echo $_SESSION['points'];
```

Comment: What triggers this? Do they submit a form or something? Or something like when they exit out of the text field which would require some javascript?

Comment: yes it is like a submit form but the thing is there are certain words that if you type them your number will get incremented so its like a points system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" size="60" name="myText" id="myText" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>      

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {            
        //echo "$_POST[myText] <br>";            

        $niceWords = array("nice", "amazing", "fantastic", "great");            
        $textArray = explode(" ", $_POST["myText"]); // create an array of all the words from the textbox

        if(! isset($_SESSION["points"])) {
            //Start the Points
            $_SESSION["points"] = 0;
        }

        foreach($textArray as $word) {
            //echo "$word <br/>";
            // check if the word is in the array of niceWords
            if(in_array($word, $niceWords)) {
                //echo "Yeah!! nice word... <br/>";
                // if it is in the array increment points counter
                $_SESSION["points"]++;
            }
        }
        echo $_SESSION['points'];

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: your code works its just when i get out of the page and then go back in it starts from 1 again if you could help me that would be great

Comment: You could use local storage instead of session, if you want to maintain the points.

Comment: Hi T.Shah is there a link that has some good teaching about local storage and also is local storage in php or javascript

Comment: These may be starting points - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp and https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html5-web-storage.php.

Comment: What if I store the points a database? Will that work because im not that good in javascript

Comment: To interact with database, I think it would be best if you use server side language like PHP. But I found this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281312/how-to-insert-data-to-a-mysql-database-from-an-html-table - it may help.

Comment: Is there anyway of doing it in php because im not good at javascript

Comment: I also tried uploading it to phpmyadmin which is a php database and It did'nt work

Comment: Upload the code that did not work and then we can help you figure out why that did not work.

Comment: $points_query = mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO user_points VALUES($_SESSION["points"])');

Comment: and also my table is called user_points and it only has one row and its called points I want to store the session in to points so I can access it more easily

Comment: Try this - $points_query = mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO user_points VALUES(' . $_SESSION["points"] . ')'); And then learn PDO.

Comment: Hello T.shah Inserting the code into the database works but I also want to display it here was my code that did not work         @ $points_select_query = mysqli_query($con , 'SELECT * FROM user_points');
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($points_select_query)) {
   echo $row["points"];
  }

Comment: Hi... I can't find anything wrong with this code. Check whether the table does have points using phpmyadmin. Also you will have a number of rows in the table. Improve the logic for insertion as well.

Comment: I only have a row called points and also I dont know what is the problem I've tried looking up on google and youtube even stackoverflow But i STILL CANT FIND THE AWNSER

Comment: I rechecked the code, there is nothing wrong with it. Your problem lies some place else. Do check using phpmyadmin, whether there is anything inserted in the table. There must be number of rows as you keep checking, it will go on inserting new rows.

Comment: $points_query = mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO user_points VALUES(' . $_SESSION["points"] . ')'); 
      $points_query_select = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT `points` FROM `user_points`');
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($points_query_select)) {
       echo $row['points'];
      }

Comment: Thank you for helping me im only 10 years old so Its a big help thankyou